# A different version of this App is already installed with the same version number

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx-webparts

This is the error message when I try to upload spfx webpart, nothing wrong webpart because I can upload it to new created site, but cant replace with existing one.

how can I resolve this?

[image: This is the ss]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this kind of situation I usually go to recycle bin and delete everything related to the app and app itself. Then go to the second stage recycle bin and do the same.

That might help, give it try. In most situations you don't need to increase version number.

Comment: "second stage recycle bin" what do you mean by that ? I already did first

Answer (score 2):

This error can occur if you don't manually update the app version number in the app manifest file (Appmanifest.xml).As you can add it on new site but not on existing so it is clearly the version number issue.

**To resolve** this issue, use a later version number in the App element of the `Appmanifest.xml` file.

["A different version of this App is already installed with the same version number" error when you try to update a SharePoint app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3059294/-a-different-version-of-this-app-is-already-installed-with-the-same-version-number-error-when-you-try-to-update-a-sharepoint-app)

Answer (score 0):

When you click on "Technical Details" you get a correlation id. Copy it then go the the SharePoint Trace Logs on your server and search for it.

You can use the following command to get the corresponding log:

```
get-splogevent -starttime (get-date).addminutes(-20) | where-object { $_.correlation -eq “..........” } | fl message > c:\errors.txt
```

Comment: And then ? Dont I suppose to delete something ?

Comment: Totally not applicable to SPO

Answer (score 0):

Delete the app from Site Contents and then from Recycle Bin. These two steps are very simple. But, sometimes you are not able to delete the app using Site Contents/UI options. In such a case use PowerShell. For example, to delete "demo-client-side-solution" app:

```
$instance = Get-SPAppInstance -Web "http://sp2016:8080/sites/teamsite/" | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq "demo-client-side-solution"}
Uninstall-SPAppInstance -Identity $instance
```

These PS commands will find, uninstall and move the app to the Recycle Bin. Now, delete it from Site Contents Recycle Bin, from site collection Recycle Bin, and Second Stage Recycle Bin. Steps to delete from site collection Recycle Bin and Second Stage Recycle Bin:

1. Go to Settings -> Site Settings -> Recycle Bin (under Site Collection Administration). Delete the deleted app from here.
2. Click the second-stage recycle bin link and delete the deleted app from here too.
   Now you are all done and can add app again.

Comment: PS commands are for SharePoint Server.